# Only two ports problem. Using iMac (Using Late 2013, 27“) as Display to connect to Macbook Pro (2019, 13”, 2 Thunderbolt 3 Ports)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

My Macbook Pro only has two USB-C ports, one of which is being used for the power cable and the other to connect an old Thunderbolt Display. I'd like to use my 2013 iMac as a second display.

Any tips on how this is feasible? I was looking at buying a CalDigit dock, but it's very expensive.

My set-up diagram attached.

Thanks[image]